# How do I delete a foreign key constraint that doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I ran across this problem to day in the process of trying to change my PSA_Landing.tblSubsDetails SubmissionID field (Which is currently the PK) to an Auto Increment field for some quick testing of something unrelated.

When trying to run:

```
ALTER TABLE `PSA_Landing`.`tblSubsDetails` CHANGE COLUMN `SubmissionID`
`SubmissionID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

I get error:

```
ERROR 1833: Cannot change column 'SubmissionID': used in a foreign key 
constraint 'fk_StatusSubmissionId' of table 'PSA_Landing.tblSubsStatus'
```

The problem being... I don't have a table PSA_Landing.tblSubsStatus... I renamed that to PSA_Landing.tblSubmissionStatus a while back.   It also does not have a FK on it.

When trying to alter tblSubmissionStatus BACK to tblSubsStatus (just to see if it helps) I get an Error 1025:

```
 Apply changes to tblSubsStatus Error 1025: Error on rename of
'./PSA_Landing/tblSubmissionStatus' to './PSA_Landing/tblSubsStatus' (errno: 
150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed) SQL Statement: ALTER 
TABLE `PSA_Landing`.`tblSubmissionStatus`  RENAME TO `PSA_Landing`.`tblSubsStatus`
```

So I then ran:

`SHOW ENGINE innodb STATUS`

And find this:

```
 ------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2016-01-24 03:15:32 7fc4410fb700 Error in foreign key constraint of table PSA_Landing/tblSubsStatus:
there is no index in the table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
table do not match the ones in the referenced table
or one of the ON ... SET NULL columns is declared NOT NULL. Constraint:
,
CONSTRAINT "fk_StatusSubmissionId" FOREIGN KEY ("fk_SubmissionId") REFERENCES "tblSubsDetails" ("SubmissionID") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Finally this lead me to try:

```
alter table PSA_Landing.tblSubsStatus
drop foreign key fk_StatusSubmissionID
```

Which expectedly gives:

```
alter table PSA_Landing.tblSubsStatus  drop foreign key fk_StatusSubmissionID      
Error Code: 1146. Table 'PSA_Landing.tblSubsStatus' doesn't exist
```

And out of desperation I tried this:

```
alter table PSA_Landing.tblSubmissionStatus
drop foreign key fk_StatusSubmissionID
```

Which yields:

```
Error Code: 1091. Can't DROP 'fk_StatusSubmissionID'; check that column/key exists
```

So in short...

**HOW do I delete constraint fk_StatusSubmissionId from table PSA_Landing.tblSubsStatus when that table does not exist??**

Comment: UPDATE.  I also can't even drop the PSA_Landing.tblSubsDetails table!  Produces error:      Cannot drop table `PSA_Landing`.`tblSubsDetails`
because it is referenced by `PSA_Landing`.`tblSubsStatus`

Comment: `ALTER TABLE PSA_Landing.tblSubsDetails ENGINE=InnoDB;` Yes, I know it's already InnoDB, but this rebuilds the table and I have seen this successfully clean up dangling foreign key constraints (which should be impossible to create, but I've seen devs do it before).  The same might be needed on tblSubsStatus.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  Was a good Idea.... but did nothing... getting same error after the fact when trying to alter the PK of PSA_Landing.tblSubsDetails

Comment: You're in a slightly delicate situation, since you have invalid dictionary metadata and a wrong move stands a chance of crashing the server.  I've voted to migrate this question to http://dba.stackexchange.com where we may be able to get some more advanced expertise.  If I remember right, you can also flag your own question and ask a moderator to migrate it (cross-posting is discouraged).

Comment: Another thought ... `SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` then create the old (missing) table with the foreign key constraint, using the same fk_StatusSubmissionID identifier, then `SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1` and drop the same table you just created.  I feel like you're dealing with a bug that was tickled back when you renamed the table and the trick now is to outsmart the system into cleaning up the metadata. I've been in similar situations with 5.1, I'm certain, and dug out from them, but failed to keep detailed notes.  What version of the server are you running? (`SELECT @@VERSION;`)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot   That was the trick!!   I had gone through that exact line of thinking once already.. but didn't use the `SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0` when I did it the first time...  Using that made take the FK out when I deleted the newly made tblSubsStatus table...    I can now modify the PK of the tblSubsDetails table as I desire.  Thanks!

Comment: @@Michael-sqlbot   Please post your reply as an answer so I can mark it off as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` causes InnoDB to disable referential integrity checking on DML and to permit *some* invalid DDL operations related to foreign keys, such as creating a table with a foreign key constraint referencing a table that doesn't yet exist, or dropping a table referenced by a foreign key, while still disallowing blatantly invalid requests, like `REFERENCES` referring to a column with a mismatched data type, or malformed foreign key definitions.

This statement operates at the session level, so it doesn't disable foreign key constraint enforcement for the entire server.  It is normally used only during the process of restoring from backups (the statement is injected into dump files by `mysqldump` and periodically executed during the reload operation) and is operationally necessary since it's not always possible to resolve circular dependencies in foreign keys (and `mysqldump` doesn't see a need to -- tables are dumped in lexical order).

**In this case, the solution was to recreate and then drop the phantom referencing table, while `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` was disabled.**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks